# UITextField on UITableViewCell stops responding to touches - possibly caused by scrolling offscreen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have UITextFields on dynamically created custom UITableViewCells. I'm using them to type data ( or pull it in from core data if its an edit) and write the data back out on editingDidEnd.

My problem is I can select the UITextFields to my heart content but if they scroll off screen and come back on again I can not touch the UITextField.

This happens both if there is no data and if the textField has data in it. The data is still there when the cell scrolls back on.

Interestingly if i touch the textField, bringing up the keyboard, scroll the cell off screen, scroll it back on then hit the return key on the keyboard I can select the cell again. So scrolling the cell while the UITextfield is theFirstResponder seems to protect it from whatever i have done wrong here.

Throwing a few lines of coding in, I have determined that my touch is triggering didSelectRowATIndexPath when its not touching the UITextField on the cell.

I'm using storyboards and my appear to be correctly using cellIdentifiers

Has anyone ever experienced this kind of behaviour and have a suggestion as to where I should be looking ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated as at this point i've spent nearly 3 days banging my head against the wall trying to work out whats going on

Thank you.

danypata heres the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    NSString *CellIdentifier;

```
if (indexPath.section == dLocation){
    CellIdentifier=@"FacilityAddressCell";
}else {
    CellIdentifier=@"FacilityGPSCell";
}

DLog(@"****CellIdentifier = %@",CellIdentifier);


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (indexPath.section) {


    case dLocation:

    {

        FacilityAddressCell *theFacilityAddressCell = (FacilityAddressCell*) cell;

        theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.placeholder = self.locationFieldNames[indexPath.row];

        theFacilityAddressCell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        theFacilityAddressCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case facilityName:
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.name;
                break;

            case webSiteUrl:
                DLog(@"self.cur.website = '%@'",self.currentOperation.website);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.website;
                break;

            case emailAddress:
                DLog(@"self.cur.email = '%@'",self.currentOperation.email);

                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.email;
                break;

            case country:
                DLog(@"self.cur.country = '%@'",self.currentOperation.country);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.enabled = NO;
                theFacilityAddressCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.country;
                break;

            case streetName:
                DLog(@"self.cur.address = '%@'",self.currentOperation.address);
                DLog(@"streetnames initial value is '%@'",self.currentOperation.address);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.address;
                break;

            case areaName:
                DLog(@"self.cur.address2 = '%@'",self.currentOperation.address2);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.address2;
                break;

            case island:
                DLog(@"self.cur.address3 = '%@'",self.currentOperation.address3);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.address3;
                break;

            case postCode:
                DLog(@"self.cur.postcode ='%@'",self.currentOperation.postcode);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.postcode;
                break;

            case phoneNumber:
                DLog(@"self.cur.phone ='%@'",self.currentOperation.phoneNumber);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.phoneNumber;
                break;

            case faxNumber:
                DLog(@"self.cur.fax ='%@'",self.currentOperation.faxNumber);
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text = self.currentOperation.faxNumber;
                break;

            case tapToBringForward:
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.enabled=NO;
                theFacilityAddressCell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.text =@"Use last location details";
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }

        cell= theFacilityAddressCell;


    }
        break;

    case dGPSLoc:
    {
        DLog( @"loading the [cell data");
        GPSLocCell *theGPSLocCell = (GPSLocCell *)cell;
        theGPSLocCell.latLabel.text= [self.currentOperation.latitude stringValue];
        theGPSLocCell.longLabel.text=[self.currentOperation.longitude stringValue];
        theGPSLocCell.lockedOrNotLabel.text = @"Locked";

        cell= theGPSLocCell;

    }
        break;
}
return cell;
```

}

Solution - The problem was I was reusing cells and a couple of them had the textfield.enabled set to NO and they were getting reused with NO as the starting value . Doh. Hope my stupidity helps someone else out somewhere down the line.

Lesson Learnt - When you reuse a UITableViewCell , or subclass of one, they retain settings from previous use and if you have certain cells of the same reuse type being formatted  differently you better make sure you are setting them all in cellForIndexPath - not just the exceptions :)

Comment: Just to be clarea which one is `UITextView` or `UITextField`, these are different things

Comment: And one more thing, you want to select the UITextView/UITextField if the user taps anywhere on the cell ?

Comment: @ danypata - sorry for the confusion should have read UITextField in all cases - juts edited that.  I want to select the UITextField when the user taps on it - not the whole cell - i just cant work out why the scrolling offscreen and back on again is causing it to not be working

Comment: can you post the "celForRowAtIndexPath" method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few places in your switch where you set

```
theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.enabled = NO;
```

Because cells are reused, if you disable the UITextField in one place, you need to set it back to enabled in the other cases.

Try adding this line right above your switch on the indexPath.row.

```
theFacilityAddressCell.facilityAddressField.enabled = YES;
```

This would explain why it works before you start scrolling. If you scroll a little bit, some of your text fields probably still work, but if you keep scrolling up and down eventually they will all be disabled.

Comment: Thank you so much . That was exactly it. I was just writing a log statement to check the enabled value on a field statement as your suggestion came through, stopped right there and just put the  enabled = NO line in and it works fine in my limited testing so far. I wish I'd asked 3 days ago - sometimes you just cant see the wood for the trees and need another eye on it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your tableView:cellForRowAtIndex: and ensure the UITableViewCell and it's subviews are correctly created each time the method is called.